# 'formRef.value' is possibly 'undefined'. in Vue 3 and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am coding a function that gets data based on a form and uses the form available from AntDesign but when I use it with Vue 3 and TypeScript it gives an error message as:

*const formRef: Ref<FormInstance | undefined>*

*'formRef.value' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)*

And here are my related code snippets:

**template:**

```js
<a-form
        ref="formRef"
        :model="DataCreate"
        name="form_in_modal"
        :validate-messages="validateMessages"
      >
        <a-form-item
          :name="['new', 's3Account']"
          label="s3Account"
          :rules="[{ required: true }]"
        ></a-form-item>
        ...
</a-form>
```

**Script:**

```js
import { ref, h, computed, onMounted, reactive, toRaw } from "vue";
import type { FormInstance } from "ant-design-vue";

const formRef = ref<FormInstance>()
const visibleCreate = ref<boolean>(false)

const CreateConfig = async () => {
  formRef.value.validateFields().then(values => { //Error here
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
        console.log('formState: ', toRaw(DataCreate));
        visibleCreate.value = false;
        formRef.value.resetFields();              //Error here
        console.log('reset formState: ', toRaw(DataCreate));
        
      }).catch(info => {
        console.log('Validate Failed:', info);
       
      });
      
};
```

I'm having trouble starting to use TypeScript, hope to get some help from you guys. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you didn't give it a default value upon construction, therefore its type is "extended" to also include `undefined` which is the default value when none is provided.

If this is the desired way of initializing it, you can use the assertion chaining `myRef!.value` (this says to typescript "Although the type says it can be null or undefined, it won't, or if it does let it fail).

Otherwise you can also use optional chaining `myRef?.value` (this says to typescript to only call the method if the value is neither `null` nor `undefined`).

Comment: Looks like it would be correct to leave myref.value? thank you very much